# how to find number which are not in a arraylist?

Tags: java

So I have a Arraylist. It is currently holding integers. I would like to get list of integers that are not in the arraylist from a certain range. For example if the range of numbers was from 1 to 5, if the arraylist contains 1,3,4  then the output should 2 and 5. The numbers stored in the ArrayList should also be unique hence I am thinking of using Hashset. This is my code so far:

```
HashSet<Integer> abc = new HashSet<>();
            while(myrs.next()){
                try {
                    //RoomIdsThatAreCurrentlyReserved.add(Integer.parseInt(myrs.getObject(1).toString()));
                    abc.add(Integer.parseInt(myrs.getObject(1).toString()));
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
```

My code is basically reading from a result set.

Comment: What about that isn't working? You can simply loop `for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)` and print `i` when `abc.contains(i)` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections), the following will work using [MutableSet](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/set/MutableSet.html). Using `MutableSet` here since you seem to be open for using `Set`.

```
MutableSet<Integer> set = Sets.mutable.with(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
MutableSet<Integer> anotherSet = Sets.mutable.with(2, 3, 4);

MutableSet<Integer> result = set.difference(anotherSet);
System.out.println(result); //[1, 5]
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example :

```
Arraylist a={1,2,3,4,5};
Arraylist b={2,3,4};
```

if you won't an output like `1` and `5`. 
then

simply used this:

```
List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>(a);
c.removeAll(b);
```

Comment: OP wants unique number only '*The numbers stored in the ArrayList should also be unique*'

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do like this,

```
 Iterator iterator = hashSet.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        int currentIteratorValue = (int) iterator.next();

        if(currentIteratorValue != 1 && currentIteratorValue != 3 && currentIteratorValue != 4){
            System.out.println(currentIteratorValue); //Prints 5 and 2
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  https://github.com/google/guava  (java 1.6)

```
        List<Integer> fullList = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4 , 5);
        List<Integer> partOfList = Lists.newArrayList(1, 3, 4 );
        FluentIterable<Integer> missing = FluentIterable.from(fullList).filter(Predicates.not(Predicates.in(partOfList)));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a 1-liner.

Given:

```
List<Integer> list; // populated elsewhere
// copy to a set if the list is large so it will perform better
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(list);
```

Then:

```
List<Integer> missing = IntStream.range(a, b)
    .filter(i -> !set.contains(i))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If the list is small you can skip the set and just use

```
.filter(i -> !list.contains(i))
```

but that is `O(n)` whereas the set contains is `O(1)`.